# Сборка Linux библиотек под Android

Tags: linux, android-ndk, makefile

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно осуществлять сборку библиотек для Linux под Android NDK. Читал несколько мануалов, но везде есть отличия друг от друга. Например, в одном мануале пишется, что на первом этапе нужно собирать скриптом ./configure. В другом - только через Android.mk. Хотелось бы конкретный и правильный порядок действий.
Необходимо собрать pcsc-lite пакет и использовать его в нативном коде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я обычно делаю так:

1. Создаю в корне дерева исходников каталог *jni*
2. Бросаю туда все свои сишные исходники
3. Создаю 2 файла: *Application.mk* (показывает целевые тулчейны) и *Android.mk* (собственно makefile)
4. Из каталога `<src>/jni` запускаю `<ndk_home>/ndk-build` (или `<ndk_home>/ndk-build.cmd` - для Windows)
5. Подбираю в каталоге `<src>/../libs` - сгенерированные либы

Comment: т.е. просто разархивируем нужную библиотеку, прописываем ее сборку в Android.mk, билдуем ndk-build и модуль готов? И не нужно предварительно никаких скриптов типа configure?

Comment: *разархивируем нужную библиотеку* если имеются ввиду исходники то да. В общем то все. Конечно, сказать проще чем сделать - надо будет помучиться с флагами компилятора, совместимостью кода и проч.

Comment: спасибо вам! буду пробовать

Answer (score 1):

Перевод с Google Translate:

Вы можете использовать «standalone toolchain» для построения проектов «configure», следуя [этому руководству](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html). Извините, насколько я знаю, у нас нет русского перевода.